# Inno Setup Rename File during packing

Tags: inno-setup, file-rename

I am trying to figure out how to rename a file in the file section while building the setup file. 
I want to include a Local.config file but extract it as Local.config.tmp
I can't figure out why Inno Setup keeps creating folders instead of renaming files. So far I have this, but it keeps creating folders named Api\Local.config.tmp.

Any ideas?

```
[Files]
Source: "Api\Local.config"; DestDir: "{app}\Api\Local.config.tmp"; Flags: ignoreversion recursesubdirs
```

Answer (score 38, accepted):

It's creating a folder as that's what you told it to do.
Try specifying a destination name:

```
[Files]
Source: "Api\Local.config"; DestDir: "{app}\Api\"; DestName: "Local.config.tmp"; Flags: ignoreversion recursesubdirs
```

Comment: I need to get more sleep! Thanks so much, I couldn't catch that for the life of me!!!!